NDVI percentage
I took pictures with my drone  for Corn field and I get the Orthomosaics and calculated NDVI at each interval, and make color for each interval as you can see in Image.
Now I want to calculate the percentage of each color /interval,or how many pixel points in each color.
How do I calculate this?



Reclassify by table to classify each interval to some value, for example <=-0.5 = 1 -0.5-1 = 2etc.

Rasterlayer unique values report, save the unique values table to for example a geopackage:


Field Calculate the percentage:
"m2"/sum( expression:="m2")*100



